# How far can a WiFi signal reach in snow?

Tags: rf, wifi, esp32

I am a kid from the mountains. If a person comes into an avalanche the people carry a device which sends and receives. The mates can then search for the victim with their one device(s).

If I would build such a device with a cheap ESP32 board with integrated WiFi protocol would it work even out of deep snow?

I am asking of personal interest.

Comment: How will your ESP detect a WiFi signal? If you make it a DHCP server wouldn't the buried user have to log in to your "router" before you detected it?

Comment: Water absorbs 2.4GHz wireless signals rather well (see microwave oven). Wi-fi signals will likely travel the best part of not very far through snow.

Comment: My idea was to program a server and simply with the mobile phone to search the signal. See where the signal gets stronger. @Tom What means not very far? cm / m? I have no idea.

Comment: Well, in open air with no rain/snow or a case, and a pcb antenna, it's 322 meters or about 1/5th of a mile. https://hackaday.com/2014/09/26/esp8266-distance-testing/ Adding snow would cause many reflections and absorption, so much less. Wifi is not an idea solution here.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Liquid water absorbs 2.4 GHz pretty well, but ice actually doesn't.

Comment: I would first test this concept without snow because I’m not convinced you can detect a random Wifi capable *client* device just by being in its range.

Comment: Avalanche beacons are an accepted technology. They transmit on 457 kHz, much much lower frequency than WiFi at 2.4 GHz, and not as severely attenuated in snow.

Comment: @Hearth : true, but you can't rely on all the water being frozen in avalanche conditions. As Mark says, LF is the way to go.

Comment: Ironically you probably could send 457 KHz with an ESP, just not with its *radio*.  But there's a bigger problem: you need each transmitter to also be a *receiver* so that those not swept up can immediately start to search for those who were.

Comment: That's why there are LVS devices on the market, known manufacturers are Ortovox, BCA, Pieps und Mammut. There are regulated frequencies for use. I don't recommend building such a device for yourself. Every avalanche search teams have such devices, As I also own and use such a Pieps "beep" device when going ski touring.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, I want to advice not to rely on whatever you are gonna craft, when it comes to your personal risk assessment when going off-slope skiing or snowboarding. There are avalanche rescue systems out there that engineered and tested to safe lives.

Now, for your question regarding the propagation of a wifi signal in snow (not in snowy air, as some have interpreted it), IT DEPENDS (as always)...

And mostly it depends on the consistency of the snow (conductivity, density, water content) and on the depth of the snow layer above soil (as the soil partly reflects signals).
Signals with lower frequency propagate better in snow, as they do in/through most materials.

I want to point you to a [IEEE paper that could give you a better understanding](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6402485) on what to think about in your hobby project and where the research is standing.
As I can not publish their research here, I think I can safely quote them and recommend reading the paper:

"As can be seen, WiFi frequency (2.45 GHz) presents an excessive attenuation with the distance, besides its greater susceptibility to the snow conditions. On that basis, lower frequencies will be better for through-the-snow communications systems."

They modeled and tested 0.4, 0.8 and 2.5 GHz signals, and compare it to the cited frequencies.

Note, they **assume a 2m depth** as their standard case for engineering, as they assume a burial below 2m has very low likelihood of survival (due to trauma, weight of snow, etc.). Other research, they cited in the paper, used a 1 m burial of the beacon and a 3 m snow layer over soil.

This does not answer your question directly, but I hope it helps developing a better understanding. Also, if you can, go test it (without getting burried) ;-)

Answer (score -3):

The wifi is limited in most countries stated for transmition of 10dbm at most (and there is a health reason for that)

Also RF signal decay in material acording to this equation - it describes how far/deep will the wave travel in a material :

[image]

What it basicly sayes is the higher the frequency and the better conductor you are trying to transmit the better the signal will go through

But since water is a good conductor and snow is a very good conductor - you will have to transmit lot more power

To answer more you have to tell us what is your receiver sensitivity and how far do you want to receive and how deep in the snow

Comment: The formula doesn't say that at all. It says exactly the opposite.

Comment: As @Andyaka points out, the opposite is true. That's why avalanche beacons operate on low frequencies, not GHz.

Comment: Thanks to all. I learned this weekend more about this topic than i my whole lifetime before. (I am working with ebeam. Penetration some 10 microns but a lot of power). I will build no such system for sure. I checked out as a newbie with the ESP32 there is a lot of cool software to do such a job. (painlessmesh or esp-now). Best wishes from Switzerland.